# Redirect the user before component gets loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to redirect the user to the homepage if there is no cookie set.

My problem is that the user may be redirected but it takes too long. For about 1 second they are still able to see the protected page. How can I prevent this?

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.hasAccess().then(result => {
    if (!result) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']).then();
    }
  });
}

private hasAccess() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.login.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
      if (hasCookie === 1) {
        return new Promise(() => {
          this.login.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
            if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
              return resolve(true);
            } else {
              return resolve(false);
            }
          });
        });
      }
      return resolve(false);
    });
  });
```

I have also tried to run my function `hasAccess()` in `constructor()` instead of `ngOnInit()` but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Maybe using ngIf for the whole component contet to avoid showing the protected content? I know it is not a solution but as workaround it could work.

Comment: Use angular [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router). They check if the routes can be visited or not before the route loads its content.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CookieGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private login: LoginService
  ) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.login.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login'));
  }
}
```

From your notes it is not clear what `this.login` is, you'll need to adjust that to fit your setup. Then you can configure your route with the following guard:

```js
const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '/whatever', component: WhateverComponent, canActivate: [CookieGuard] }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a **RouteGuard** like this:

```
export class ComponentRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        if (this.isCookieSet) {              
                return true;              
        } else {
            this.router.navigate([`unauthorized`]);           
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'test', component: YourComponent, canActivate: [ComponentRouteGuard]},
    { path: 'unauthorized', component: UnAuthorizedComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use Angular gurad.

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class YourGuard implements CanActivate {
      path: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[];
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

      constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

      canActivate() {


        if (your logic) {
         ....
        }
        else redirect to ...
    }

    in your routing.module :



    {
          path: 'your path',
          loadChildren: () => import('path')
            .then(m => m.YorModule),
            canActivate:[YourGuard]
        },
```